# Should I define get_absolute_url() if the url is not unique?

Tags: django, django-models

In the Django framework, models can define a `get_absolute_url()` method. The method is used to create urls for instances of the model and it is considered a good practice to define and use this method.

Is it still a good practice to define this method even if the generated urls are not unique?

Example:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('xxx:project_details', args=(self.id,))


class Item(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('xxx:project_details', args=(self.project.id,))
```

Currently, the `Item` instances can only be seen in a list on the `project_details` page and I intend to keep it that way. The `get_absolute_url()` method returns the project details url. This means that all Items of the same project return the same url. Is that okay? I found it useful, because some generic views use `get_absolute_url()` and automatically redirect to the correct page. However, I am new to Django and want to know whether this will cause problems later.

Comment: You could make it more elegant by writing `return self.project.get_absolute_url()`. There is no fundamental problem with this, although it might be a bit strange that it links to a common place, usually `get_absolute_url` links to some sort of "detail view".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: I would advice *not* to do this. Usually the `get_absolute_url` links to a "unique identifier" for that object.

> Is it still a good practice to define this method even if the generated urls are not unique?

The documentation on [**`get_absolute_url(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) mentions that:

> Define a `get_absolute_url()` method to tell Django how to calculate
>   the **canonical URL for an object**. To callers, this method should
>   appear to return a string that can be used to refer to the object over
>   HTTP.
>
> (...)
>
> Similarly, a couple of other bits of Django, such as the syndication
>   feed framework, use `get_absolute_url()` when it is defined. If **it
>   makes sense for your model’s instances to each have a unique URL**,
>   you should define `get_absolute_url()`.

In mathematics and computer science a [*canonical form* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form) says that:

> (...) The distinction between "canonical" and "normal" forms varies by subfield. In most fields, a **canonical form specifies a unique representation for every object**, while a normal form simply specifies its form, without the requirement of uniqueness. (...)

So this hints that `get_absolute_url` makes more sense if the URLs that are generated are unique. After all, the `get_absolute_url` aims to show the details of that specific object. You use it to `redirect(some_object)`, etc.

Although it will of course not raise errors, it is not very common to use `get_absolute_url` to link to the detail page of a *parent* object.

If you proceed, you might implement it as: `return self.project.get_absolute_url(..)` instead of implementing the same `reverse(..)` logic, since if you later alter the `get_absolute_url` of the project, then the `get_absolute_url` of item will be updated as well.

Comment: Okay, I did not know that a canonical form is a unique representation of the objects.